# Correct use of kafka global statestore for lookups

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

It would be nice to hear some opinions whether this is a good idea because I don't have previous experience in implementing something like this:

**Requirement:**

I have two topics: topic book-info, topic category-info.
As I process messages from topic book-info, I need to lookup some metadata which came from topic category-info.
Ideally, each topic should be processed in a separate app and codebase because of our design guidelines (I'm specifying this in case it's a constraint for global statestore). Also, we are using KStreams and Spring Kafka.

**I had the following idea:**

App1: Read messages from topic category-info and based on specific condition either save them into global statestore or delete them from global statestore .

App2: Read messages from topic book-info, do a lookup in global statestore to produce the final record.

Will this work and are there any better practices?
Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, global statestore will be a bottle-neck for the performance issue when it grows over a period of time, especially for the long running production data pipeline, unless you have a better lifecycle implemented on such statestore.

Since you are designing two separate applications for two different source topics, better option would be doing a lookup through an external DB for the records and it will be having a better control. Or, you can use the KSQL Streams/Table running interactive queries.